# Is it correct and natural to say "find someone by their phone number" in the context of searching someone's information in a system?

Tags: phrase-choice

Can you please tell me if it is correct and natural to say *find someone by their phone number* in the context of searching someone's information in a system? For example:

> I don't see any appoinments set up under your name in our system. Let me try to **find you by your phone number**.

If it doesn't sound natual, does *let me try to find you **with** your phone number* sounds better?

If they don't sound natural, would you give me alternative phrases to convey the message.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's quite correct and natural. It's another case of an understood word 'using', which would be after the 'by'.

Possibly a better way would be 'using your phone number' (in this case the 'by' is understood.

Probably the most natural way of saying this would be simply: "Let me try  your phone number".

Again, there are 'understood' words in this shorter example. The full sentence, would be: ""Let me try and find you by using your phone number", but no one would say that in practice.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Would you tell me if it's also natural to say "let me try to find you with your phone number"?

Comment: It's OK, but "let me try to find you with from your phone number", would probably be better.

Comment: Just to confirm, is it really "find you with from your phone"?

Comment: "find you from your phone number"

Comment: An equally common alternative, "Let me *look you up* by/with your phone number"

Comment: Just want to say hat the OP's original sample sentence sounds better to me than any of the suggested alternatives.

Answer (score 3):

One of the uses of "by" is when talking about the way things are organized:

- These books are arranged alphabetically **by** the author's last name.
- Please line up **by** height from shortest to tallest.
- This table of the wealthiest people in the world is ordered **by** their net worth.

This makes it a great choice for the example situation, in which the system can be indexed "by" phone number (as well as perhaps in other ways, like "by" the person's name). You *could* choose "with", since the phone number would help you in the task of looking up (just like "I'll paint this house **with** a paintbrush"), and it wouldn't be odd, but the "lookup" sense of "by" makes it a more likely choice.